# PHP Cant get single value from database row

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, row

im trying to get a single value from a database row but i get nothing no matter what i use. I tried

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
$product_cat = mysql_result(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT product_category_id FROM am_product_product_category WHERE product_id=1  limit 1"),0);
```

and

```
$product_cat = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT product_category_id FROM am_product_product_category WHERE product_id=1  limit 1"));
```

and

```
$product_cat = mysqli_fetch_field(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT product_category_id FROM am_product_product_category WHERE product_id=1  limit 1"));
```

and

```
$product_cat = mysql_fetch_object(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT product_category_id FROM am_product_product_category WHERE product_id=1  limit 1"));
```

and

```
$product_cat = mysql_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT product_category_id FROM am_product_product_category WHERE product_id=1"));
```

But when i echo $product_cat i get nothing (it should echo 1). Can you please tell me what im doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: That is because you are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. Both are different database API. The former is deprecated in the future versions of PHP.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: you should only use either mysqli or mysql. try yo use mysqli will be better

Comment: Okay but then why wont the 3rd one work either? Im using mysqli_fetch_field along with mysqli_query only

Comment: what you want into `$product_cat`?

Comment: $product_cat must print out "1" only (without the quotes).

Answer (score 0):

becouse you are mixing mysqli_* and mysql_* function, use mysqli_* function only

try this:

```
$product_cat = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT product_category_id FROM am_product_product_category WHERE product_id=1"));
echo $product_cat['product_category_id'];
print_r($product_cat);
```

Comment: That one seems to work but it echoes an array. I need a single value only. Thanks.

Comment: try `echo $product_cat['product_category_id'];`

Comment: That one works but is there no other way to do it so $product_cat prints out the single value?

Answer (score 0):

Are your sql query correct ?

First check it and try again with `mysqli_fetch_row`.

If also you have problem you can try the `mysqli_fetch_array` and then use the `$result[0]` which is the field.

Otherwise, you can get the result an print the result with `print_r($result)` to check the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $product_cat = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT product_category_id FROM am_product_product_category WHERE product_id=1  limit 1");
   $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($product_cat);
   echo $row["product_category_id"] ;
```

If you have many values to fetch then use this:

```
  $product_cat = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT product_category_id FROM am_product_product_category WHERE product_id=1  limit 1");
   while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($product_cat)){
       echo $row["product_category_id"] ."<br />";
       }
```

Comment: Thanks but is there no other way to do it so $product_cat prints out the single value?

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this example.I think this example is helpful to you.**

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select *from employee_details where emp_id= '$id'  ");
echo "Emp-Id";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
  echo ". $row['emp_id'] . ";
mysqli_close($con);

                  (or)
```

**try this one also**

```
$product_cat = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_category_id FROM am_product_product_category WHERE product_id=1")->fetch_object()->product_category_id;
```

use this code.

Comment: That does work but its not what i intend because its too much code and i only need one value.

Comment: Only one. the one contained in that field.

Comment: use this code$id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select *from employee_details where emp_id= '$id'  ");
    echo "Emp-Id";
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
      echo ". $row['emp_id'] . ";
    mysqli_close($con);

Comment: The problem with that is that i would need to use something like $product_cat[0] to print the value but $product_cat alone must print the value without any arrays.

Comment: above comment you told me that one value is enough.above example is work for what the form field you enter the id is,that id value will be print.

Comment: Yes, i know. But i need $product_cat alone to print the value, without queries. It cant be another way.

Comment: try this one.......$product_cat = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_category_id FROM am_product_product_category WHERE product_id=1")->fetch_object()->product_category_id;

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer provided by Programmer999:

```
$product_cat = $con->query("SELECT product_category_id FROM am_product_product_category WHERE product_id=1")->fetch_object()->product_category_id;
```